# Reference a nested list in yaml in another yaml file

Tags: yaml, freemarker

I have a yaml document that looks like this:

```
outterkey:
  innerkey:
    - name: someName
      fave: ["Apple"]
    - name: someOtherName
      fave: ["Mango","Orange"]
```

How can I reference this in another yaml file like this:

```
key: ${outterkey.innerkey}
```

Doing this throw the error where freemarker expected a string but got a sequence.
I did some searching but only found solutions for simple lists using "join".

Comment: What are you trying to output? What or which value?

Comment: I am hoping that I can transfer: 
    - name: someName
      fave: ["Apple"]
    - name: someOtherName
      fave: ["Mango","Orange"] to the new yaml file as it shows in the original yaml

Comment: Your definition of `outterkey` doesn't look like freemarker declaration. I am not familiar with yaml and freemarker mix so I am not sure how it transfers. But if you want individual values, you need get those values with freemarker built-in for sequences.

Comment: FreeMarker has no built-in functionality to transform a data-structure to YAML. Also YAML is sensitive to indentation, and so generating it with FreeMarker would be really painful.